# Reputation moved to meta from SO, ability to answer removed

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

The first question I answered was moved to meta from SO, causing my reputation to go from 36 to 1.

I believe that this caused my ability to answer questions on SO to be removed.

Comment: It shouldn't have done. However, if you have other down-voted answers that were deleted you might be answer blocked - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers

Comment: Well, too bad your only upvoted answer was posted on an off topic question.

Answer (score 3):

That was the only upvoted answer you had.  You have a handful of others (4 out of your 5 answers) that were downvoted and/or deleted, which contributes a lot more to the answer ban.

See [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/1288) for details on what to do next.